# UrlReferrer VS Session VS Query Parameter

Tags: session, referrer, query-string

I have **2 search-pages** and **1 result-page**. 
The result-list on the result-page is a list of URLs.

The URLs are dependent of the search-page, so if the user comes from search-page1 he gets a different URL to the user who comes from search-page2.

So on the result-page I have to know from which search-page the user comes.
First I tried it with UrlRefferer, but if the result-list has too many results, I use paging and if the user clicks on the second result-list I loose the UrlReferrer...

What is the best way to do this? To use Session or better use a query parameter in the URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question, this is only for a single request. So better you can pass as a request parameter. Session will unnecessary hold the value for the whole pages which is not appropriate. And unless you update the value in session parameter, it will keep hold the old value only.

Is it possible for you to hold the value in a script variable?

Comment: Nearly a single request... as I said, when there are many results and the user wants to see the results on the second (third,...) page, he sends another request. So I have to pass the parameter to the next page

Comment: Is it possible to post some code samples and what kind of prog/script language are you using?

Comment: I'm using C#, but this is a general question. My project is too bis to post some code samples to this problem, but I think the question should be clear without a sample

Comment: Yes, it's general question. But it's still not clear whether you are using Java Script or any framework such as JQuery for pagination. Or you are everytime making a server call for the pagination (when you click on next/previous button, it may make a server call)

However I would suggest to use JQuery Pagination and maintain a javascript varible which can retain the value i.e. from which page it came from. This way you are not going to make another request for when user clicks on the second result-list.

Comment: I'm using a PagedDataSource to build paging in a repeater. So it is not with JavaScript, and it makes everytime a server call.
Unfortunately I can't change the pagination. But you are right, with JavaScript maybe it would be better.

Comment: Then Session variable for this seems a good idea. But again there is a headache of adding/removing that attribute from session properly.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO session is a simpler solution, so you doesn't have to set query parameters every time user change page.